Python script deploys smart contract on sandbox local network, but application link fails with "Error: Application failed to load"
Here is my code:
from beaker import * 
from pyteal import * 

app = Application('Testing123')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Build the app and export it
    app.build().export('./TestFolder')
    
    # Get the accounts (ensure the localnet is defined correctly)
    accounts = localnet.get_accounts()
    acc1 = accounts[0]
    

    # Initialize the Algorand client
    alogd_client = localnet.get_algod_client()
    
    
    # Create an application client instance
    app_client = client.ApplicationClient(
        client=alogd_client,
        app=app,
        sender=acc1.address,
        signer=acc1
    )
    
     
    # Create the application on the blockchain
    app_id, address, txid = app_client.create()
    
    # Print the transaction ID of the application creation
    print(txid)

I have a Python script that successfully deploys a smart contract on a sandbox local network, but when I try to check the application through the link https://lora.algokit.io/localnet/application/1003, I get the following error:
Application Error: Application failed to load
However, when I use various APIs, I can interact with the deployed contract without any issues. The problem only occurs when accessing the application through the link.
Has anyone encountered this issue, or does anyone know what might be causing it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Not familiar with algorand, and not trying to point out an obvious, but going to the link shows an error, which is likely why you are unabled to load the app. Subscription failed to retrieve data

@ViaTech If you go to link with out algorand sandbox running on your local host, you will get the error you get. This is all fine, I just don't get why apps are not loaded.

Ah got it, okay bad comment on my part.
